# Bug in a Scroll of DataGrid - WPF?

Tags: wpf, scroll, datagrid

I hope you can help me with this:

I have a DataGrid with 20 rows and every time I check the checkbox in one of the columns, a label value is increasing by 100 each time or decreasing if unchecked. So, once I've checked all the rows the value of the label will be 2000.
just like you see below:

[image]

When I reduce the height of the DataGrid a Vertical Scroll appear and when I'm checking the checkboxes the procedure seem to be similar as you can see:
[image]

But if I scroll the vertical bar downwards, other checkboxes appear enabled or checked, Any idea why?
In this case I've checked the first six checkboxes and the value of the label is 600, which is fine, but why the other ones appear checked ?
thanks..

[image]

Here is the code I've used:

```
<StackPanel Name="spUno"  Width="auto " LostKeyboardFocus="spUno_LostKeyboardFocus" >
        <Button Name="btn_Accion" Margin="5" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Accion" Click="btn_Accion_Click">
        </Button>
        <Label Name="lbl_Muestra" Width="300" Margin="5"/>
        <DataGrid Name="dg_Pruebas" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding}" Height="200" Width="300"
                 SelectionChanged="dg_Pruebas_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Path=id}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nombre" Binding="{Binding Path=nombre}" ></DataGridTextColumn>
                <!--<DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="check" Binding="{Binding Path=isChecked}" ></DataGridCheckBoxColumn>-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header >
                            <TextBlock>Ver 
                            </TextBlock>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="ck_Prueba" Visibility="{Binding Path=visibility}" Checked="ck_Prueba_Checked" Unchecked="ck_Prueba_Checked" ></CheckBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>


private void ck_Prueba_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox check = e.OriginalSource as CheckBox;
        Objeto obj = dg_Pruebas.SelectedItem as Objeto;
        if (obj == null)
            return;
        if (check.IsChecked.Value) 
        {
            lbl_Muestra.Content = (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Muestra.Content)+Convert.ToInt32(obj.valor)).ToString();
        } else 
        {
            lbl_Muestra.Content = (Convert.ToInt32(lbl_Muestra.Content) - Convert.ToInt32(obj.valor)).ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably just recycling for speed
Try

VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"

Comment: It seems to work better, but when I have several items like 30, and the user scroll the grid for many times the problem appear again. I mean, the items checked before, appear unchecked.... Any idea how to solve it ?